# GNOME Login Theme Downloads (Mint 16 Petra)

Tags: linux-mint, gnome

I am running **Linux Mint 16 Petra Mate** and I am trying to figure out why I am unable to **add a downloaded login theme** from gnome-look.org

[This](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Blue+Swirl?content=30846) is the theme I want to install. However, the Login Window manager doesn't recognize the *Theme archive*

I have done some searching around and most sites say I have to type the command

```
echo $DESKTOP_SESSION
```

to figure out if I am using GNOME

My terminal just replies with `default` . Guessing I am not quite there yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using Mate  (or so you tell us), which is based on Gnome3. However, the theme you are trying to install is for Gnome2:

[image]

In their infinite wisdom, the Gnome devs have completely changed the login manager (called `gdm`) and it is not compatible with 2.x themes. To further complicate things, Mint has forked `gdm` and instead uses `mdm` which *should* be compatible with `gdm` but might not be.

Comment: Should I set my default session to run MATE or RunXclient script? Is there a difference?

Comment: In the Options tab of the same settings menu (Login Window) - There is the option of setting the default session to be either of these. Is one preferred over the other?

Comment: @JoeBennett neither will affect this issue. The `Xclient` script is basically if you want to roll your own session using `xinit` or `startx`or something.